# Getting bytes written to SQL database for integer column, want integer to be written

Tags: python, sql, django, plotly-dash

I am writing data from a dash app to a SQL database setup by Django and then reading back the table in a callback. I have a column that the value should either be 1 or 2 but the value is as below in the SQL database:

[SQL Database view of column that should contain 1 or 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi5Mr.png)

When this is read back to a pandas dataframe it appears as b'\00x\01x... or something along those lines, which then gets read wrong when it needs to be used.

The django code for the column is:

```
selected = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)
```

I am writing and reading the data using SQLAlchemy. Number appeared perfectly in pandas dataframe before involving SQL. Read and write code:

```
select = pd.read_sql_table('temp_sel', con=engine)

select.to_sql('temp_sel', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by specifying the variable as an integer before sending to SQL as follows:

```
j = int(j)
```